# Runtime Error Sfml with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, runtime, runtime-error, sfml

I m using Qt when I m compile the project in Qt It runs, but when I run from the explorer I get runtime error.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>


int main()
{
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"jkllmkjl");
    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event e;

        while(window.pollEvent(e)){
            if(e.type==sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.display();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I already paste dlls into .exe directory.
Can someone help me ?

Comment: first of all read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) article. Also why do you think we know what Sfml is? Did you at least use site search? For example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590299/importing-dll-into-qt) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858399/using-external-lib-dlls-in-qt-creator) links?

Comment: Can you tell us what the runtime error message you get is?